# Error deploying to rbenv with Capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, rbenv

I'm new to Capistrano and having trouble debugging an error. Searching suggests this error could be an environment issue of picking up the wrong version of ruby (it's almost certainly not the referenced file as it works fine in test). Using a Capistrano task to dump the ruby version everything looks fine. Running the commands directly on the server works fine, too. I'm using rbenv on the server.

The error:

```
 * executing `deploy:assets:precompile'
 * executing "cd /home/deployer/apps/happenate/releases/20120424002545 && bundle exec rake RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets assets:precompile"
   servers: ["happenate.com"]
   [happenate.com] executing command
** [out :: happenate.com] rake aborted!
** [out :: happenate.com] /home/deployer/apps/happenate/releases/20120424002545/config/initializers/session_store.rb:3: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting $end
** [out :: happenate.com] ...sion_store :cookie_store, key: '_happenate_session'
** [out :: happenate.com] ^
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitely some sort of ruby environment issue. After cleaning everything up with a proper rbenv environment, the error is gone.